# Recover data from deleted storages

Tags: data-recovery

I have Ubuntu 16.04 on a Dell server and a storage of 70 terabyte. I lost all my data in the storage.

Can any one help me to find any way to recover my data with their paths? The paths of files are very important. Thanks a lot.

Comment: were they deleted with the rm command?  Also, what filesystem?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, could you add details. So it may get better chance to resolve the issue. See https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask